# Como posso salvar arquivo TXT no diretório C:\ usando C#?

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, winforms, armazenamento

Estou tentando fazer um pequeno programa para rolagem de dados e quero que ele salve um arquivo .txt que armazene as rolagens, para que possa ser lido posteriormente. O programa está praticamente inteiro pronto, todas as funcionalidades funcionando, mas quando tento selecionar o diretório onde o .txt vai ser salvo como o `C:\` ele não me deixa utilizar, provavelmente por causa de problemas de permissão.

Como vou fazer um instalador desse programa para distribui-lo na internet, preciso salvar em um diretório que seja padrão em qualquer PC, e por isso achei que o `C:\` seria o ideal. Será que poderiam me dar uma mãozinha?

Comment: Explique melhor seu problema, coloque o código que está utilizando pra isto. Mas já adianto que o C:\ é o oposto do ideal. E provavelmente tem problemas de permissão mesmo.

Comment: Tá tentenado salvar direto no C:\? Ou numa subpasta? Qual o erro que dá quando tu tenta salvar? Poste o código para nós entendermos o que você está fazendo.

Comment: Executa ele como administrador, provavelmente você não tem direitos suficientes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você está tentando salvar em uma pasta dentro do C pode ser que ela não exista,s e for esse o caso, você pode verificar se existe e criá-la caso seja o caso:

```
var dirPath = @"C:\Temp\";
var filePath = dirPath + "arquivo.extensao";

// Verifica se o diretório não existe e cria 
if (!Directory.Exists(dirPath))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);

// Da mesma maneira para o arquivo
if (!File.Exists(filePath))
    using (File.Create(filePath)) { }
```

Comment: Isto é péssimo, no meio do caminho a situação pode mudar e você tem uma *race condition*.

Comment: Cara, você não precisa criar outra resposta. Você pode editar a sua anterior.

Comment: Como assim @bigown? Pode explicar melhor?
@jbueno vou lembrar da próxima. Valeu

Comment: Se tem dúvidas, faça uma pergunta.

Comment: Não vejo necessidade de uma pergunta sobre, só seria interessante se você explicasse o porque esse código poderia causar uma race condition. Essa é uma forma de verificar se o arquivo que vou utilizar realmente existe antes de tentar fazer qualquer coisa. Não está certo esse pensamento?

Comment: Muito obrigado pessoal, especialmente ao Pedro Camara! Deu tudo certo aqui  :)

Answer (score 1):

`System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()` é apenas um wrapper para uma chamada nativa para `GetTempPath (..)` em Kernel32 .

Dê uma olhada [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364992(VS.85).aspx)